# How to import and call a Python function in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to use a function from a python module, in my Jinja template inside a Flask application. How do I import the module or pass the function to the template so that I can use it?

Comment: I arrived here with exactly the same question.  The OP seems perfectly clear and well worded to me.  And the answer was useful, so I'm voting to re-open, and I will update the title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First approach. If you want to pass function only to one template, you can pass function to template as variable. For example

```
render_template("index.html", func=f)
```

And then call it in template, `{{ func(1) }}`

If you want function or variable accessible in all templates (globally). You can add them during flask application initialization to `app.jinja_env.globals` dict, like:`app.jinja_env.globals['func'] = f`